# SDL_PollEvent causes screen to wake up after xset dpms force off

Tags: c++, linux, x11, sdl-2

I have a program that turns the screen on and off with `xset dpms force on/off` and also calls `SDL_PollEvent(&e)` in a loop. After turning the display off with `xset`, any call to `SDL_PollEvent` causes the screen to wake up, even without any input. I can comment out the `SDL_PollEvent` call and it doesn't happen. Is there something I need to do with an event or something to prevent the screen from turning on? Updated with minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
atomic<bool> SCREEN_ON(true);
atomic<bool> RUNNING(true);
atomic<bool> SERVER_CONNECTED(false);

std::string exec(const char *cmd) {
  char buffer[128];
  std::string result = "";
  std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
  if (!pipe)
    throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
  while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL)
      result += buffer;
  }
  return result;
}
double get_time() {
    static const Uint64 freq = SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();
    static const Uint64 begin_time = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    Uint64 current = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    Uint64 elapsed = current - begin_time;
    return (double)elapsed / (double)freq;
}

void handle_input() {
  SDL_Event e;
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){}
}

void monitor_thread() {  
    while (RUNNING) {
        double time = get_time();
        if (time < 15)
            SERVER_CONNECTED = false;
        else if (time < 35)
            SERVER_CONNECTED = true;
        else
            SERVER_CONNECTED = false;

        cout << "server status: " << SERVER_CONNECTED << endl;
        cout << "screen_on status: " << SCREEN_ON << endl;

        handle_input();
        SDL_Delay(1000);

        if (SCREEN_ON && (!SERVER_CONNECTED)) {
            cout << "TURNING SCREEN OFF\n";
            SCREEN_ON = false;
            exec("sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off");
        }
        if ((!SCREEN_ON) && SERVER_CONNECTED) {
            cout << "TURNING SCREEN ON\n";
            SCREEN_ON = true;
            exec("sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force on");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Uint32 initflags = SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO;
  SDL_Init(initflags);
  Uint32 window_flags =
      SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_INPUT_GRABBED;
  SDL_Window *window =
      SDL_CreateWindow("title", 25, 25, 800, 600, window_flags);
  SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
  SDL_EnableScreenSaver();
  SDL_GLContext gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
  glewInit();
  thread update_thread(monitor_thread);
  glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  while (RUNNING) {
    if (!SCREEN_ON) {
      cout << "zzz...\n";
      SDL_Delay(2000);
      continue;
    } 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_Delay(16);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<s>The screen will turn itself back on very shortly after `exec("sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off");`, before the next call to turn it back on.</s>

Nevermind, SDL_PollEvent can only be called in the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`SDL_EnableScreenSaver()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EnableScreenSaver).

[More info](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQUsingSDL#Why_does_SDL_disable_my_screensaver_by_default.3F):

> **Why does SDL disable my screensaver by default?**
>
> Many applications using SDL are games or screensavers or media players
>   where the user is either watching something for an extended period of
>   time or using joystick input which generally does not prevent the
>   screensaver from kicking on.
>
> You can disable this behavior by setting the environment variable:
>   `SDL_VIDEO_ALLOW_SCREENSAVER=1` This can be set globally for the user or
>   on a per-application basis in code.
>
> In SDL 2.0.2 this can also be changed by setting the hint
>   `SDL_HINT_VIDEO_ALLOW_SCREENSAVER`.
>
> Additionally, SDL 2.0 provides the function `SDL_EnableScreenSaver()`.